# How to limit the outbound traffic (bandwidth)?

Tags: networking, libp2p

We are hosting some parachain full nodes on the cloud. However we found that 80% of the costs come from the internet traffic, and specifically, we found that the outbound traffic of the relaychain client has been skyrocketing. We noticed that it's possible to limit `--out-peers` in substrate, but even a few peers can still create huge traffic (e.g. new client downloading the blocks).

Is it possible to limit the outbound traffic bandwidth rate in Substrate?

Comment: I think the best way to do this is to limit the process at system level.

Answer (score 1):

You can not limit the traffic of your node directly? How should that even work? You stop answering requests etc?

The only way to bring down traffic is to restrict the number of `--in-peers` and `--out-peers`. The traffic should be proportional to the number of peers you are connected to. When you decrease this number the traffic should go down.

Comment: It's kinda like running a bittorrent client. When limiting the traffic, essentially it should limit the in and out traffic for each peer in a somehow "fair" way. Or even simpler, to limit the node to not offer any historical block download (even it's an archive node). By limiting the peers, there's still a high chance that the peers want to download the full block history.

Comment: So your node would only be a leecher in the network?

Comment: I don't think not serving block history is equal to being a leecher. What if a team wants to a few boot nodes which are not supposed to support the block downloading, but just peer discovery and become a hub for latest transaction / block relaying?